# How to give a gap between bar chart and frame

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, bar-chart

I try to make group bar chart with label in the top each of bar, but the label always cross the frame. I want to make the label doesnt cross the frame, but the label still on top of the bar. [my bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QFTk.png)

```
def autolabel(rects):#label di atas bar
for rect in rects:
    height = rect.get_height()
    ax.annotate('{}'.format(height),
        xy=(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, height),
        xytext=(0,3),  # 3 points vertical offset
        textcoords='offset points',
        ha='center',va='bottom')

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 6, 10. #w,h
labels = ['1', '2', '3', '4','5']
men_means = [20, 34, 30, 35, 98]
women_means = [25, 32, 86, 20, 25]
shemale_means = [45, 37, 95, 25, 22]

x = np.arange(len(labels))  # the label locations
width = 0.35  # the width of the bars

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(ncols=1, nrows=4, constrained_layout=True)

for ax in ax1.flat:
    rects1 = ax.bar(x - width/2, men_means, width, label='Testing Prediction')
    rects2 = ax.bar(x+ width/2, women_means, width, label='Training Prediction')

    ax.set_title('Title', fontsize=12)
    ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
    ax.set_xticks(x)
    ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
    ax.tick_params(axis="x", labelsize=8)
    ax.set_ylim(bottom=0, top=100)
autolabel(rects1)
autolabel(rects2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, one possible way is to move up the top boundary of the plot by changing the top limit from `100` to `115`:

```
ax.set_ylim(bottom=0, top=115)
```

If you want to be sure to keep the same `yticks` just add:

```
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 105, 20))
```

[image: Here's what i got]

---

The full code is here below:

```
def autolabel(rects):#label di atas bar
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.annotate('{}'.format(height),
            xy=(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, height),
            xytext=(0,3),  # 3 points vertical offset
            textcoords='offset points',
            ha='center',va='bottom')

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 6, 10. #w,h
labels = ['1', '2', '3', '4','5']
men_means = [20, 34, 30, 35, 98]
women_means = [25, 32, 86, 20, 25]
shemale_means = [45, 37, 95, 25, 22]

x = np.arange(len(labels))  # the label locations
width = 0.35  # the width of the bars

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(ncols=1, nrows=4, constrained_layout=True)

for ax in ax1.flat:
    rects1 = ax.bar(x - width/2, men_means, width, label='Testing Prediction')
    rects2 = ax.bar(x+ width/2, women_means, width, label='Training Prediction')

    ax.set_title('Title', fontsize=12)
    ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
    ax.set_xticks(x)
    ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
    ax.tick_params(axis="x", labelsize=8)
    ax.set_ylim(bottom=0, top=115)
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 105, 20))

autolabel(rects1)
autolabel(rects2)
```